# include called with wrong number of arguments

Tags: c++11, cmake

I tried to compile MEPP library. I created a find module "FindCGAL.cmake" as follow:

```
IF(CGAL_INCLUDE_DIR AND CGAL_LIBRARIES)
    SET(CGAL_FOUND TRUE)
ELSE(CGAL_INCLUDE_DIR AND CGAL_LIBRARIES)
    FIND_PATH(CGAL_INCLUDE_DIR basic.h
        /scratch/softs/cgal/4.3.0/64/sequential/gcc/4.4.7/include/CGAL
        $ENV{ProgramFiles}/CGAL/*/include/CGAL
        $ENV{SystemDrive}/CGAL/*/include/CGAL
    )
    FIND_LIBRARY(CGAL_LIBRARIES NAMES CGAL libCGAL
        PATHS
        /scratch/softs/cgal/4.3.0/64/sequential/gcc/4.4.7/lib
        /scratch/softs/cgal/4.3.0/64/sequential/gcc/4.4.7/lib/CGAL
        $ENV{ProgramFiles}/CGAL/*/lib/ms
        $ENV{SystemDrive}/CGAL/*/lib/ms
    )

    IF(CGAL_INCLUDE_DIR AND CGAL_LIBRARIES)
        SET(CGAL_FOUND TRUE)
        MESSAGE(STATUS "Found CGAL. New Hossein: ${CGAL_INCLUDE_DIR}, ${CGAL_LIBRARIES}")
        INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CGAL_INCLUDE_DIR} $ENV{CGAL_CFG})
    ELSE(CGAL_INCLUDE_DIR AND CGAL_LIBRARIES)
        SET(CGAL_FOUND FALSE)
        MESSAGE(STATUS "CGAL not found. New Hossein")
    ENDIF(CGAL_INCLUDE_DIR AND CGAL_LIBRARIES)

ENDIF(CGAL_INCLUDE_DIR AND CGAL_LIBRARIES)
```

and in the CMakeList.txt:

```
# Find CGAL libraries
FIND_PACKAGE(CGAL COMPONENTS Core)
IF(CGAL_FOUND)
    INCLUDE(${CGAL_USE_FILE})
    MESSAGE(STATUS "Found CGAL: ${CGAL_LIBRARIES}")
    MESSAGE(STATUS "Found CGAL 3RD PARTY LIBRARIES: ${CGAL_3RD_PARTY_LIBRARIES}")
ELSE(CGAL_FOUND)
    MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "CGAL not found. Please set CGAL_DIR.")
ENDIF(CGAL_FOUND)
```

During compilation I receive the following CMakeError:

```
 CMake Error at src/components/Analysis/Curvature/CMakeLists.txt:48 (INCLUDE):
  include called with wrong number of arguments.  Include only takes one
  file.
```

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to set "CGAL_USE_FILE".

Comment: should I set it as CGAL_INCLUDE_DIR or CGAL_LIBRARIES??